# Collapse-tag-tooltip not showing up in el-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I have an el-select as stated below. Note that I have used an alias name **Select** instead of **el-select**

```
             <Select
                v-else
                v-model="data.dockId"
                filterable clearable multiple 
                collapse-tags
                collapse-tags-tooltip
                class="select-default"
                @change="changeData($event,'id', true)">
                <Option
                  v-for="item in dockList"
                  :key="item.id"
                  :label="`${item.reference_id} - ${item.name}`"
                  :value="item.id" />
              </Select>
```

Now the problem is, I am able to select multiple items but on hovering **+1**, it doesn't show me the list of selected items in tooltip. Could anyone help me debug this.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `collapse-tags-tooltip` is not available in Element for Vue 2. It is available only in Element Plus for Vue 3